# In a doubly linked list, How many pointers are affected on an insertion operation?

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list, insertion

I had an interview yesterday. As it started, the first thing that the interviewer asked was

" In a doubly linked list, How many pointers will be affected on an insertion operation ? "

---

Since, he didn't specifically asked where to insert I replied that it depends on how many nodes are there in DLL.

As total pointers that will be affected will depend on whether the list is empty or not and where insertion takes place.

But, he didn't say anything whether I had convinced him or not.

Was I correct or maybe I missed something ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What *precisely* does "affected" mean? Read? Written? Dereferenced? And what *precisely* does "insertion" mean? Does it include searching for the place to insert or does it refer only to the *actual* insertion operation?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I guess "affected" here means, that when I insert then I have to change the pointers next and prev to the new node .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends on whether we are inserting the new node in the middle of the list (surrounded by two nodes), or at the head or tail of the list.

For insertions in the middle of the list, to splice in a new node as follows:

```
A --- B
   ^^ splice M in here

A.next = M
M.prev = A
B.prev = M
M.next = B
```

Hence four pointer assignments take place.  However, if the insertion be at the head or tail, then only two pointer assignments would be needed:

```
TAIL (insert M afterward)

TAIL.next = M
M.prev = TAIL
```

Comment: So, after all it does not depends on total number of nodes, right ?

Comment: The amount of pointer math you do does not depend on the number of nodes.  _However_, this is not to say that the running time for insertion into a linked list does not depend on the size of the list.  Rather, for a sorted list it would still take `O(N*lgN)` time to find the insertion point _before_ we have even begun the actual insert operation.

Comment: Why O(N * log N)? For a sorted *array*, it can be done in O(log N) through binary search, for a sorted *list*, it should not be more than O(N) (worst-case, you need to look at all elements). I'm not clear why you would need to look at more than all elements in the worst case.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sorry, I meant `O(lgN)` for binary search.

Comment: The O(log N) bound for binary search requires random access, which linked lists don't have. Binary search in a linked list is O(N), IOW the same as linear search, so not really worth the implementation complexity.